# CSS animated icon before link

Tags: html, css, position, css-animations

In my header I have this arrangement for showing a link and an icon before it using padding.

```
<li class="small-icon icon-pm">
    <a href="/messages" role="menuitem">
        <span>MESSAGES</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Now I have added an animation for the background image but, obviously, it effects the text “MESSAGES” too.
Is there a way I can make it effect only the background while keeping the same setup and not reverting to using `< img >` before `< a >` ?

You can get a rough idea of what I mean/am talking about here http://codepen.io/RhinoFreak/pen/WxbYVY

Much thanks!

Comment: Yes, perform the animation on the `.icon-pm::before` only instead of on the `.icon-pm`

Comment: is[this](https://jsfiddle.net/nv3yvq6o/) what you want?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Thanks for quick reply. I tried doing so, but now my icon doesn't even appear. Can you do little edit on the codepen.io and show me? Many thanks!

Comment: @Lal thanks! That's one way to do it and yes that is one solution but my question (sorry if it wasn't clear) is to do it without editing my html because lots of stuff depends on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv3yvq6o/2/)

Instead of applying the class that does the animation, to the whole `<li>` you can just add a `<span>` and apply the class to the `<span>`.

The updated `<li>` would be as follows:

```
  <li>
    <span class="small-icon icon-pm-newerr"></span>
    <a href="#">messages</a>
  </li>
```

**UPDATE**

To make the `<a>` vertically centered, change the CSSa little bit as below

```
li a,
li span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv3yvq6o/4/)

Comment: That works, I guess there's no other way,  thanks I will make the edits then :)

Comment: I ran into a little issue now. The moment I apply `display:inline-block;` the text link right next to it get's shifted downwards. :/
Maybe these images will be able to make you understand my issue:
[link]http://i.imgur.com/l7K28X5.png[/link]
[link]http://i.imgur.com/VqDXiJz.png[/link]

Comment: thanks! I could give you direct link of where it's applied but it's a private forum for now so I can't!


EDIT! THANKS SO MUCH :D IT WORKS